# hamburger menu: click area is too large

Tags: html, css

I created a simple CSS hamburger menu for smartphone view.
Link: https://zellkraft.ch/gesundheitsberatung.php

The menu works fine but the click area ist too large. The menu opens even if i klick horizontal aside the 3 lines. What could be the problem?

my HTML code:

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="click">
<label for="click">
<div class="hamburger">
    <div class="hamlinien linie1"></div>
    <div class="hamlinien linie2"></div>
    <div class="hamlinien linie3"></div>
</div>
</label>

<ul class="ganzesmainmenu">
    <li class="mainmenu versteckt"><a href="gesundheitsberatung.php" class="versteckt">Gesundheitsberatung</a></li>
    <li class="mainmenu"><a href="elektrosmog.php">Elektrosmog</a></li>
    <li class="mainmenu"><a href="hautgesundheit.php">Hautgesundheit</a></li>
    <li class="mainmenu"><a href="asea-amriswil.php">ASEA</a></li>
    <li class="mainmenu"><a href="bemer-amriswil.php">BEMER</a></li>
    <li class="mainmenu"><a href="gabriela-haeni.php">Über&nbsp;mich</a></li>
    <li class="mainmenu"><a href="kontakt.php">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li class="mainmenu"><a href="gesundheit-links.php">Links</a></li>
</ul>
```

my CSS code:

```
    @media (max-width: 479px) {
ul {
    display:none;
    margin-top:60px;
    }   
#click {display:none;}
#click:checked ~ ul {display:block;}
#click:checked ~ label .linie2 {opacity:0;}
#click:checked ~ label .linie1 {transform:rotate(-45deg); top:30px; transition: transform 0.4s;}
#click:checked ~ label .linie3 {transform:rotate(45deg); top:30px; transition: transform 0.4s;} 
.hamlinien {
    width:40px;
    height:4px;
    background-color:black;
    border-radius:4px;
    position:absolute;
}   
.linie1 {
    top:12px;
    }   
.linie2 {
    top:28px;
    }   
.linie3 {
    top:44px;
    }   
.hamburger {
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    border-radius:4px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin-bottom:-30px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    }   
}
```

Comment: It is the label you click on. Take **display: block;** away and it will work fine.

Comment: Whitout display:block; the menu doesn't appear anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Just add `box-sizing: border-box` in `.hamburger` css class. This will make sure that the padding is also included in the specified width so that the width does not become more than the specified width (60px).

```css
@media (max-width: 479px) {
   ul {
     display: none;
     margin-top: 60px;
   }

   #click {
     display: none;
   }

   #click:checked~ul {
     display: block;
   }

   #click:checked~label .linie2 {
     opacity: 0;
   }

   #click:checked~label .linie1 {
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
     top: 30px;
     transition: transform 0.4s;
   }

   #click:checked~label .linie3 {
     transform: rotate(45deg);
     top: 30px;
     transition: transform 0.4s;
   }

   .hamlinien {
     width: 40px;
     height: 4px;
     background-color: black;
     border-radius: 4px;
     position: absolute;
   }

   .linie1 {
     top: 12px;
   }

   .linie2 {
     top: 28px;
   }

   .linie3 {
     top: 44px;
   }

   .hamburger {
     width: 60px;
     height: 60px;
     border-radius: 4px;
     padding-left: 10px;
     padding-right: 10px;
     margin-top: -20px;
     margin-bottom: -30px;
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     box-sizing: border-box;
   }
 }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="click">
<label for="click">
  <div class="hamburger">
    <div class="hamlinien linie1"></div>
    <div class="hamlinien linie2"></div>
    <div class="hamlinien linie3"></div>
  </div>
</label>
<ul class="ganzesmainmenu">
  <li class="mainmenu versteckt"><a href="gesundheitsberatung.php" class="versteckt">Gesundheitsberatung</a></li>
  <li class="mainmenu"><a href="elektrosmog.php">Elektrosmog</a></li>
  <li class="mainmenu"><a href="hautgesundheit.php">Hautgesundheit</a></li>
  <li class="mainmenu"><a href="asea-amriswil.php">ASEA</a></li>
  <li class="mainmenu"><a href="bemer-amriswil.php">BEMER</a></li>
  <li class="mainmenu"><a href="gabriela-haeni.php">Über&nbsp;mich</a></li>
  <li class="mainmenu"><a href="kontakt.php">Kontakt</a></li>
  <li class="mainmenu"><a href="gesundheit-links.php">Links</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposals. Unfortunately they don't work...

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the ***position: relative*** from the class ***.hamburger***

```css
.hamburger {
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    border-radius:4px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin-bottom:-30px;
    display:inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem...